# What is the correct "pay to the order of" to get a U.S.passport?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

I need to make out a check to submit/pay for my passport application, but I am a little confused about what to write. Do I just put down, "U.S. Department of State," or do I enter the headquarters' mailing address (2201 C Street, Vancouver, Washington)? I don't want to have to rewrite a check!

Comment: Don't you pay for the passport application fee at the post office?

Comment: You have it right, "U.S. Department of State" according to this [site](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/fees.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you're [paying for your passport application](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/fees.html#payment_instructions) in the United States, you make your check or money order payable to "U.S. Department of State". The USPS advised me when I went in this year that your name and date of birth should appear on the check/money order (in case it gets separated from your application).

You must also pay a separate $35 execution fee to the agency which accepts your passport application (this fee was $25 prior to April 2018). This must be made payable to the agency accepting your application, but most such agencies will accept debit/credit cards for this payment.

If you're paying for your passport *outside* the United States, contact the embassy or consulate for payment instructions.

Comment: A lot of US Embassies overseas do not take personal checks, just cash and sometimes credit cards.

Comment: It used to be the case that when applying for a passport in person at a post office, in addition to the check to the State Department for the Application Fee, you had to write a *separate* check for an Execution Fee, and as I recall the latter was to be made out to the Postal Service.  Has this changed?

Comment: @NateEldredge You pay the $25 Execution Fee when you apply for your first passport at any location.  But yes that fee is made payable to the location accepting your passport, be it the post office or passport office or embassy

Comment: When I got my most recent passport (2012), at the post office, they told me the $25 was for them to take a photo and that I wouldn't have to pay it if I already had an acceptable photo.  (Which I had.)

Comment: @WGroleau Oh, they charged me separately for the photo. But I got to keep one of the two photos they printed. That'll be useful if I have to apply for a visa anytime soon.